# React native read and parse SMS from iphone inbox

Tags: iphone, react-native, sms

I am developing a react native app where I need to read and parse text messages (leads) from a certain number.

Once I get SMS access, I want to parse it and extract the phone number. Then I want to send a pre-defined text to that phone number automatically from my phone.

Is this possible to build this app for the iPhone? If so, then what resources I should use?

Comment: Tell me, will you install this kind of application on your phone? who reads your SMS and do automatic stuff?

Comment: one of my clients wants to automatically respond to leads coming to their phone (first message only) from their personal phone number. So just looking for possible solutions. Kindly let me know if we can build any such solution.

Comment: You can read OTP refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601552/how-to-programmatically-read-incoming-text-messages-on-ios

Comment: don't think if reading OTP will solve my problem